# How does Ethereum handle undeterministic results from oracles?

Tags: blockchain, nodes, oracles

Since when a transaction is done, every node in the blockchain runs the smart contract in their machines, what if the smart contract is calling an oracle to get a random value? Shouldn't it return different output for every node?
How does Ethereum handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the other way around: the **oracle puts data in the smart contract**. Once the data is there all the nodes will see the same value.

For your scenario - yes, the number is random. It is generated by the oracle. But once it is stored in the smart contract, all the nodes will run their code against the same value.

[This article](https://medium.com/@mustwin/building-an-oracle-for-an-ethereum-contract-6096d3e39551) describes some techniques you can use to build your own oracle. Even if you don't intend to build one yourself, it's a good read, because